# using autocomplete box in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, autocomplete, telerik, ria

i am currently displaying data in the radgrid controls of telerik, i want to add an autotextbox over the column named "Name". how can i do this?

my radgrid only displays data and i want that whenever user enters into textbox a list of name pops up just like in stackoverflow web site.

please help..i have been using silverlight,wcf ria services,telerik controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AutoComplete textbox from the Silverlight 4 Toolkit. The toolkit is an advanced set of controls that are not part of the core Visual Studio library. To download & install, you can head [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). Once you have it installed, you add a project reference to System.Windows.Controls add this to your UserControl declaration:

`xmlns:input="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input"`

This gives you a reference point for the Silverlight Toolkit, specifically the input controls. Once that's done, here is an example of using the autocomplete textbox:

`<input:AutoCompleteBox IsTextCompletionEnabled="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{StaticResource SampleEmployees}" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"/>`

This comes directly from the documentation from the Silverlight Toolkit. [Link here](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html). Click the 'AutoCompleteBox' in the left menu (under heading: Input). Once loaded, you can view the XAML/C# by clicking on any one of the items at the bottom of the window, such as 'AutoCompleteBoxSample.xaml' or 'AutoCompleteBoxSample.xaml.cs' This should give you the start/code you're looking for.

In your case, you'll also need to create a cell template for the radgridview. Here's a quick sample of what that might look like:

```
<radControls:RadGridView x:Name="registerGridView" 
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False">  
        <radControls:RadGridView.Columns> 
            <radControls:GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn /> 
            <radControls:GridViewDataColumn Header="Client" /> 
            <radControls:GridViewDataColumn Header="Site" />  
            <radControls:GridViewDataColumn Header="Name">  
                <radControls:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate> 
                    <DataTemplate> 
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">  
                            <input:AutoCompleteBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"/>
                        </StackPanel> 
                    </DataTemplate> 
                </radControls:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate> 
            </radControls:GridViewDataColumn> 
        </radControls:RadGridView.Columns> 
    </radControls:RadGridView>
```

Comment: i specifically need autocomplete box rather than combo box.

Comment: Well the [Silverlight Toolkit has an autocomplete box](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) that's probably your best bet. Probably should have led with that. Just used to Telerik :) [Here's another article](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/203770/477530.aspx#477530) that has several options/discussions

Comment: I am not familiar to xaml and i need an idea for xaml code and c sharp ...but,i am only getting help from asp.net.  please help me with xaml,c # and autocomplete box over telerik radgrid items to be searched

Comment: Edited response with more detail for you.